# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in mongoDB/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting the following error in my code. Another thing is that the constant 'Product' on line 3 is undefined and I don't know why. Please help me out. The entire code is on github at this [link](https://github.com/akashwebsite/doubt)

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
|     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
|     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
--- property 'topology' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at stringify (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
at module.exports.getAllProducts (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/controllers/productController.js:14:19)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

Code -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require('../models/productsModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');

module.exports.getAllProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // Get all products
        const products = Product.find();

        // console.log(products);

        // Send response
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            results: products.length,
            data: {
                products,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(404).json({
            status: 'fail',
            err: error,
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to wait for the query to return data before sending the response.

You can use `await` in front of the query

```js
const products = await Product.find();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vishnu

Comment: I had the same problem but await resulted in a syntax error because my function was not labeled "async". So yes, 'await' but also make sure your function is async.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem. *facepalm